# Correlation length in massive scalar field theory

Tags: statistical-mechanics, dimensional-analysis, correlation-functions

What does correlation length mean in free massive scalar field theory? For fields with mass $m$, the correlation length is $1/m$, implying that the fields die off after that length. So, there will almost be no correlation further than that length scale. I wanted to know what it means and how it comes.

Comment: The (equal time) two-point function decays as $e^{-r/\xi}$ (with some algebraic prefactors) where $r$ is the distance between the two points, and $\xi$ is the correlation length.

Comment: @MengCheng If you wrote that as an answer I would upvote it.

Comment: Would you please elaborate a bit about how mass is coming to the picture and why it should be for massive fields?